# Passing promises through functions React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, fetch

I'm brand new to react native and I've been browsing through snippets of code and am confused as to how promises are passed along.

I have this event handler `onRefresh()` that is called when I pull down on a flatlist and I'm trying to have it use the return of `apiSearchDB` when it returns true/false.

```
onRefresh = () => {
  this.setState({...}, () => {
    return this.apiSearchDB()
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  })
}

apiSearchDB = () => {
    return fetch('/some_endpoint')
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((json) => {
       this.setState({
          ...
       }, () => {return true})
       return true;
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
       return false;
    })
 }
```

The line `console.log(response);` only prints `undefined` and I can't figure out why.

Could my handler also be written as

```
onSearch = () => {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var response = this.apiSearchDB();
       response
          ? resolve();
          : reject();
        }
   });
 }
```

or `onSearch = () => {...}` and `function onSearch(){...}`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read more about using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) (good article - [We have a problem with promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html)). However, two basic rules that will help you in this case are are:

- The value returned from a promise is wrapped in a promise.
- Promises can be chained.

The `apiSearchDB` should return a promise that contains the `json` as the resolved value, and `error` as the rejected value:

```
apiSearchDB = () =>
  fetch('/some_endpoint')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => json)
    // can be removed unless you want to do something with the error before passing it on
    .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
```

The `onRefresh` (or `onSearch`) method should get the promise from `apiSearchDB`, and add it's own chain. Resolve promise should be handled with the `then` handler. If it's the rejected value, it will be handled by the `catch` handler:

```
onRefresh = () =>
  this.apiSearchDB()
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);

      // do something with response          
      this.setState({...}, () => {

      });

      return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);

      // do something with error          
      this.setState({...}, () => {

      });
    });
}
```